# How do I allow users to "Like" our Facebook company profile using the Facebook SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

We have a company profile page on Facebook where we interact with our customers. We would like to get as many users to "Like" us as possible, because it allows us to post something and have have it appear in their feeds.

How do I allow users to "Like" our Facebook company profile using the Facebook SDK for iOS? We have been able to login/logout and post on other people's walls just fine, but how do we get people to "Like" us using the iOS SDK?

Comment: I'm very curious if you figured this out?  I've been trying to post a like to my company profile, but Im continually getting an error.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is possible, it will just involve finding the right information in the Facebook Graph API documentation (which is often tricky): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

The relevant section on that page would be under "Publishing" where it says

> You can publish to the Facebook graph by issuing HTTP POST requests to the appropriate connection URLs, using an user access token ...
>   You can "like" a post by POSTing to https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes

Where obviously POST_ID should be replaced by the ID of your Facebook page. I don't think this is in the Facebook SDK for iOS but there is definitely code in there for making POST requests to the Graph API, so it would involve digging around in there for a bit.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot neilkimmett.. You save a HELL lot of my time. I was using the same API, but was using GET method instead of POST. You were spot on with your answer :)